# How to access a csv file in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I'm working on a Ruby on Rails app, where I need to load some data in csv format to a JS script to process.

my csv file is in `app/assets` and my js file is `app/assets/javascripts` which I process in `assets.rb` using :

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( myscript.js )
```

in `myscript.js I make an ajax call to the csv file :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "assets/mycsvfile.csv",
    async: true,
    success: function (csvd) {
        // processing csv data
        },
    error: function(e) {
        var errorMsg = e? (e.status + ' ' + e.statusText) : "";
        console.log(errorMsg);
        },
    dataType: "text"
    });
```

I still get

> 404 file not found

How can I load that csv file ?

Thanks

Comment: How often does the CSV file change? Unless it changes *constantly* then its pretty wasteful to have the browser process it on every request. Consider processing it once, on the server, whenever it changes and saving the result, then sending the pre-processed JSON to the browser instead.

Comment: @Jordan thanks, I'm trying it

Answer (score 2):

Put the file `mycsvfile.csv` in the "public" directory of your Rails app.

Then, you will be able to load it directly from a `YOURDOMAIN/mycsvfile.csv` request.

EDIT:

As you don't want to use public URL, you have either to use HTTP server auth or Rails Server to handle the file download.

For the Rails app to handle the file download, use the `send_file` command.
You will be able to check proper users permissions in the controller before serving the static file.

Example:

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
    # Stream a file that has already been generated and stored on disk.
    def download_pdf
        client = Client.find(params[:id])
        send_file("#{Rails.root}/files/clients/#{client.id}.pdf",
          filename: "#{client.name}.pdf",
          type: "application/pdf")
    end
end
```

Source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#sending-files

Comment: thanks, I forgot to mention that I don't want that csv file to be accessed from a url

Comment: It you don't want the CSV file to be accessible from a URL, then how do you want to pass it to your Ajax call? (do you mean that you don't want the file to be publicly accessible? or do you refuse the URL approach?)

Comment: I don't want it to be publicly accessible, like localhost:3000/assets/mycsvfile.csv shouldn't be downloadable